# If Joe has $\$1500$ to invest at $12\%$ per year compounded monthly, how long will it be before he has $\$2100?$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms, finance

[image]Here is my work so far:
$A=P(1+r/n)^{nt}$

$2100=1500(1+0.12/12)^{12t}$

$2100/1500=(1.01)^{12t}$

Here is the part that I am stuck on. Would I take the natural log of both sides? And in general when solving for problems similar to the one that I have given, when would I take the natural log of both sides

Comment: Take logs. Natural or common, doesn't make any difference (so long as you use the same base on both sides of the equation).

Comment: Okay, let me go ahead and do that now. Also I uploaded a picture of what the problem is asking for @GerryMyerson

Comment: Joe should start on-line classes to teach people (for a fee)  how to invest with $12\%$ interest per year. He will get his $\$2100$ much faster this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use logs when you have positive quantities, which in this type of problems always happens. So :

$$A=P(1+\frac{r}{n})^{nt} \iff$$
$$ \log{\frac{A}{P}}= nt \log{(1+\frac{r}{n} )} \iff $$
$$ t = \frac{\log{A}-\log{P}}{n\log{(1+\frac{r}{n})}}$$

This is the general formula for $t$.

Comment: I obtained the value t=2.8 is that correct? @Tortar

Comment: yes, it is !  @gnatgnat2019

Comment: Perfect! Thank you for your help. @Tortar

Answer (score 0):

$$
\frac{2100}{1500} = (1.01)^{12t}
$$

$$
\text{ln}(\frac{2100}{1500}) = \text{ln}((1.01)^{12t})
$$

$$
\text{ln}(\frac{2100}{1500}) = 12t \times \text{ln}(1.01)
$$

$$
\frac{\text{ln}(\frac{2100}{1500})}{\text{ln}(1.01)} = 12t
$$

$$
t = \frac{1}{12} \times \frac{\text{ln}(\frac{2100}{1500})}{\text{ln}(1.01)}.
$$

Comment: I obtained the solution t=2.8 is that correct? @Victor S.

Comment: Yes, it is correct, if you round to one decimal place. I got 2.817932... I would round it to 2.82!